# the right way of specifying website files in html

Tags: links, html5, w3c-validation

i specify my website's internal files  like this  for my website: www.mscaspian.com  `
but when i validate it with w3c it says there is an error in the last part, '>' .
i don't understand why this is wrong. is there anything i'm missing?
it says:

> Bad value ../Nexus components/css/component.css for attribute href on element link: Illegal character in path segment: not a URL code point.Syntax of IRI reference:
>   Any URL. For example: /hello, #canvas, or http://example.org/. Characters should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as %20.

i read the NFC link they provided but Really couldn't figure out what's wrong with it!
Using HTML5 and CSS3

Comment: Who knows.... You haven't shared your HTML, please edit your question and include information that is required for us to be able to give a solid answer.

Comment: what do you need? my question is about a link and i posted the exact link.

Comment: I'll edit it for you... gosh :)... in future please use `PRE` formatting on CODE, as it will be filtered out by Stack Exchange.

Comment: alright i'll do that, now please remove it from hold and if you can  answer my question ;)

Comment: What markup you using? HTML5, HTML4 XHTML?

Comment: Nevermind, Edited it.. Added `%20` and `/>` you have a space between components if thats an error then delete it, or use `%20`.

Comment: Once this question has been updated to include the information needed to troubleshoot this it can be reopened. Providing a link to the site in question is **not** considered acceptable. The relevant code must be placed in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Nexus components/css/component.css">`

XHTML/HTML4 Use:

`<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../Nexus%20components/css/component.css' />`

HTML5 Use:

`<link rel='stylesheet' href='../Nexus%20components/css/component.css' />`

Full Code Used:
[image]

Comment: error still exists. invalid markup!

Comment: I've updated the answer and tested in both HTML4 and HTML5 and works fine and dandy!